# jQuery Datepicker in while loop

Tags: php, jquery-ui, datepicker, while-loop

I am completely new to jquery and php, and I'm trying to generate a table within a while loop that shows a list of students. Each student has a field that allows the user to enter the date in which they handed-in coursework.  To enter this date, I am trying to use jquery-ui datepicker.

However, at the moment datepicker only comes up for the first entry.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions with how to overcome this!

Many thanks in advance,
Katie

Comment: What selector are you using to reference the datepicker placeholders and how are the placeholders structured? Do they all have the same class? Different IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create id of textfiled different for each.and put jquery code in while loop with that id
then it will work for you

e.g.

```
while($data){
<input id="datePicker_<?php echo $data->studentId; ?>" name="datePicker">
}
```

And provide same id for jquery code

This will work

Comment: The code below is currently in the Head.  Does this need to go in the while loop as well?:

<script type = "text/javascript">

$(init);
function init() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker ();
}

</script>

Comment: Yes! and change the id with you ID

<script type = "text/javascript"> $(init); function init() { $("#datePicker_<?php echo $data->studentId; ?>").datepicker (); } </script>

Comment: Hi Shivam, when viewing the source code, it's picking the script up, but my site is not displaying the datepicker?

Comment: This is the source code: 

<script type = "text/javascript"> 
$(init); 
function init()
 { $("#datePicker_16005271").datepicker ();
  }
   </script>

Comment: (CONT ....)

<form action= 'update_assignment_students.php' method= 'POST' >

<tr>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'StudentNo' value = '16005271'/></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'FirstName' value = 'Katie'/></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'LastName' value = 'Oates'/></td>
<td><input id = 'datepicker_16005271' type = 'text' name = 'HandinDate' value = ''/></td>
<td><input type = 'submit' name = 'Update' value = 'Update'/></td>
</tr>

<input type = 'hidden' name = 'AssignmentID' value = ''/></form>

Comment: <form action= 'update_assignment_students.php' method= 'POST' >
  <tr>
    <td><input type = 'text' name = 'StudentNo' value = '16005271'/></td>
    <td><input type = 'text' name = 'FirstName' value = 'Katie'/></td>
    <td><input type = 'text' name = 'LastName' value = 'Oates'/></td>
    <td><input id = 'datepicker_16005271' type = 'text' name = 'HandinDate' value = ''/>
    <script type = "text/javascript"> $(init); function init() { $("#datePicker_16005271").datepicker (); } </script></td>

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have confused you.  Above was the source code from when trying to load the page.  I'll show you my actual PHP code ...

Comment: while ($sqlrows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$StudentNo=$sqlrows["StudentNo"];
$FirstName=$sqlrows["FirstName"];
$LastName=$sqlrows["LastName"];
$HandinDate=$sqlrows["HandinDate"];

?>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 
$(init); 
function init()
 { $("#datePicker_<?php echo $StudentNo;  ?>").datepicker ();
  }
   </script>

<?php

Comment: (CONTINUED .....)
echo "<form action= 'update_assignment_students.php' method= 'POST' >\n";

echo "
<tr>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'StudentNo' value = '$StudentNo'/></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'FirstName' value = '$FirstName'/></td>
<td><input type = 'text' name = 'LastName' value = '$LastName'/></td>
<td><input id = 'datepicker_$StudentNo' type = 'text' name = 'HandinDate' value = '$HandinDate'/></td>
<td><input type = 'submit' name = 'Update' value = 'Update'/></td>
</tr>
";

Comment: Can you give me link of your site page. Where you are using this code

Comment: May be you have not included jquery file

Comment: I have included the jquery file, because it was able to display the datepicker for the first student before I posted my issue on the forum.  Also, I'm sorry but my site is on an internal server so unfortunately I cannot provide the link ...

Comment: The jquery file is still in the Head.

Comment: Katie can you send me your file on my email address shivomkaras@gmail.com

I will check it and will send you back with resolving issue